# How to get the last value in a series using grafana with a ES backend

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm using grafana's singlestat  plugin to graph some time series data in an elasticsearch 5 backend. In selecting the value to use i don't see the possibility to use the current or last value in the series. Can someone tell me how i can do this with ES as i think that it's because I'm using ES instead of influxdb why I'm having this problem

Answer (score 3):

You could change `Stat` to `current` to the get latest value.

[image]